# How to rename the Struts 2 token parameter

Tags: java, security, struts2, access-token, struts2-interceptors

How to rename the Struts2 Token Parameters?

if we use `<s:token/>` tag while form submit by default Struts2 will generate URL something like this

```
?name=name&struts.token.name=struts.token&struts.token=8E1USQZ5LHG120FU4YUZJAMPOUT4OVP3
```

by using this `<s:token name="suid"/>` tag we can rename the "struts.token" parameter. Struts2 will generate URL something like this

```
?name=name&struts.token.name=suid&suid=8E1USQZ5LHG120FU4YUZJAMPOUT4OVP3
```

How can we rename the "struts.token.name" parameter?

Comment: I think it isn't possible... but we accept patches or Pull Requests :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter is used by the [`TokenHelper`](http://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/util/TokenHelper.html). There no extension points are given for this bean. You can provide your own implementation by extending token interceptors and overriding their methods only and replace references of token helper inside them.

You should check this links:

- [Interceptors](http://struts.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html)
- [Introducing Interceptors](http://struts.apache.org/docs/introducing-interceptors.html)
- [Writing Interceptors](http://struts.apache.org/docs/writing-interceptors.html)

Comment: Thank you roman, How to override TokenInterceptor? Can u give any example?